# CSS media queries not working

Tags: css, media-queries

Basically i am trying to block some styles for a particular width range(240px to 480px). Between this range, i do not want certain styles to get rendered.

To be more clear:

I want color:#000 for all other device widths except for the width->240px to 480px. How i can i make use of media not all queries. Hope i am clear..:(

Is this the correct syntax :

I have :

```
 @media not all and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 480px), not all and (min-device-width: 240px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

What im trying :

```
@media not all and( (min-width: 240px and max-width: 480px )and (min-device-width: 240px and max-device-width: 480px) ){
```

Can i combine the two :

```
 @media not all and (min-width: 240px and max-width: 480px) {}
 @media not all and (min-device-width: 240px and max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you originally have is the correct syntax. The others are invalid.

The `not` in each media query negates the media query itself, so if the browser matched a certain media query, then `not` means it has to ignore that `@media` rule. If the browser doesn't match the media query, then `not` means it has to apply the rule.

When you combine two or more `not` media queries in a single rule, at least one of them has to evaluate to true (or "not false") in order to use the rule.

If you are trying to `not` *all* the tests at once, then you need to link them all using `and`:

```
@media not all and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 240px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

But depending on the devices you're testing with this may or may not make sense.

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do, which isn't very clear at the moment.

Comment: Okay basically im trying to add some styles which shouldnt come at those particular widths, but for every other width, it should work

Comment: You should really put that in the question. Your edited title doesn't make things any clearer.

Comment: Do i need to use @media screen ...?

Comment: @Roy M J: See if my example helps then. You'll need to test it with the relevant devices yourself.